# Sort Cursor object without query to database android

Tags: android, sorting, cursor

I have a cursor object which I get in callback method. that object is not sorted. I wanted to sort that cursor object.
can anyone tell me how to sort that Cursor object.
I am not firing any query to database.
I know the method of sorting while querying database.
But how to sort the Cursor which i already have.?

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly sort data from cursor alternative is 
you first extract data in some List then sort it using you need

```
public class CustomComparator implements Comparator<YourObject> {
    @Override
    public int compare(YourObjecto1, YourObjecto2) {
        return o1.getStartDate().compareTo(o2.getStartDate());
    }
}
```

Sort using

```
Collections.sort(Database.arrayList, new CustomComparator());
```

Comment: its a lengthy process.

Comment: yes,but for now there is no other alternative for that.

Comment: Ok..thank you for the answer, But I am looking for some shortcut method.

Answer (score 0):

Use Comparator from collection framework in java

Comment: Collections.sort(Object,sortByOrder_id());

public Comparator<Object> sortByOrder_id(){
  return new Comparator<Object>() {
   @Override
   public int compare(Object first, Object second) {
    return toInteger(second.order_id).compareTo(toInteger(first.order_id));
   }
  };
 }